# PHP Preg_replace not working with <br> and new line together

Tags: php, regex

I have a Json file with html content in some rows, how ever everytime I try to use preg_replace to match this combination of a break and new line it doesn't work.

For example, `<br>
No atraviesa el papel`

Want to replace with: `<br>No atraviesa el papel`

Already tried:

```
$pattern = '/<br>\n/m';
$subs = '<br>';
$json_response = preg_replace($pattern, $subs, $json_response);
```

Im looking to remove the newline and leave only the `<br>`

Comment: Are you sure you have `\n` and not a windows new line? Does `<br>\v` work?

Comment: @user3783243 I clearly need more coffee. You're probably on the right track with `\v` although it might need to be `\v+` if there's a `\r\n` sequence

Comment: .. you could even do `<br>\s*` if you just want to remove all whitespace after a `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with a positive lookahead.
And then substitute the match with an empty string.

```
/(?<=<br>)\s*\R/
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TRMNGV/4)

- edit: added a match for white space, if there is any after the `<br>`
- edit: made it more concise and universal with the help of @ user3783243

Comment: There is no `g` in PHP. `\v` covers vertical spaces, for any type of new line `\R` should be used.

Comment: @user3783243: So you would suggest `/(?<=<br>)\s*\R/m` would be more concise and universal solution?

Comment: Probably `/(?<=<br>)\s*\R/`. The `m` also has no context because there are no anchors

Answer (score 0):

Is it something you are looking for?

```
<?php

$json_response="<br>
No atraviesa el papel
";

$tobe = "<br>No atraviesa el papel
";

$pattern = '/<br>([\r\n]+)/is';
$subs = "<br>";
$json_response = preg_replace($pattern, $subs, $json_response);

echo $json_response;
echo "\r\n", $json_response==$tobe?"Matched":"Did not match";
```

It outputs: Matched.

Comment: ([\r\n]+) could be (\s+) as well.